# How to Pass 2D array to a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array in C++ which takes input from the user. I want to pass this to a function.
sample Code I written is:

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void fun(int arr[n][m])
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    int arr[n][m];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            cin>>arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    fun(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the correction I should do in code so I can access the 2d array in function?

Comment: A variadic array function argument requires all but the most component dimension be specified by provision as arguments to said-same function. That, assuming your C++ compiler supports them by extension, because standard C++ does **not**.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to take three arguments.

The array pointer, m, and n

```
void fun(int *arr, int n, int m) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: Close. You can often brute-force a 2D `int` array to fit in a `int *`, but doing so breaks strict aliasing. The type of the array is actually `int * [m]`, and since `m` is not a constant, all bets are off.

Comment: what should i do then